# how to display content in else part?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using this code for print my post category .if wordpress has the post means it excute correctly it displays the post of category otherwise it display your post not here.
  i did not get else part properly it displays the dark screen is coming .i want to display else part correctly on my display.

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                    <div class="clear"></div>


              <?php endwhile; ?>
```

help me to solve this problem .Thanks..

Comment: The only time that the `else` will not work is if there's an error generated. The `if(have_posts()):` just checks if `have_posts()` returns an array or false. If it's false the conditional will fire. What does, `it displays the dark screen is coming` mean? I'm not familiar with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to handle the `else` statement:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
Handle your else code here...
<?php endif ?>
```

As you'll see, we simply use `else:` and then `endif` to hook into the else clause. Please not that I also added the closing `</div>` which was missing from your code.